# Importing Classes and working with Libraries

Tags: python, class, tkinter, pygame

So I have a class that I am working on and when I am finished with it, I want to import it into the game that I am working on. The main source code for my game has Tkinter imported, so my question is, do I need to import Tkinter into my seperate class file in order to use it in my game like normal or can I leave that out since Tkinter is already imported into the source code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, as a general rule you need to import tkinter in every file that uses tkinter.

Comment: Does that rule also apply to any other modules or libraries imported?

Comment: @Terminatrix3 Yes, you have to import modules before you use them. There are circumstances when you can pass modules or functions into other modules or functions, but generally speaking every file needs to import the modules that it uses.

Comment: Thank you so much this helps out tremendously.